# Java--I'm putting together a GUI interface for homework. What component do I use to make this text box? [pic]?

Tags: user-interface, textbox, slider

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K6DC.png

The picture is the example provided. I'm assuming when I slide the slider the text in the grey box will change based on the action listener's logic. I know how to do this, I just don't know what the grey box is called to initialize it. Is that a JTextField?

Comment: what language are you using? Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a JTextField but is read-only. field.setEditable(false); is what you want to use after you have initialized the JTextField. See [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jtextfield/create-read-only-non-editable-jtextfield/) for an example.